# How to iterate the ruby array without negative indices

Tags: arrays, ruby, data-structures, iteration

I need to compare each value in ruby array with previous and next value.

**Update**

#### Example:

```
[1,2,4,5]
```

I want to check like this. `(a[i] with a[i-1] and a[i+1])`

```
1 with only next value  # as there is no prev value
2 with prev & next value
4 with prev & next value
5 with only prev value # as there is no next value
```

In ruby, the a[-1] is not pointing to nil, it is taking last value. So, unable to iterate. Is there any alternate solution?

#### Tried

1. changing array to `[nil,1,2,4,5,nil]`

but getting following error

> comparison of Fixnum with nil failed (ArgumentError)

2. instead of `0..n` I tried `1...n`. but this does not solve my issue.

#### Question:

How to ignore negative indices for first(i-1) and last(i+1) element in ruby array.

Answer (score 3):

Your comparison doesn't really make sense. You are comparing everything twice, but if someone *really* is changing the array while you are iterating over it, you have much bigger problems than this (and you still will not catch modifications made to the beginning of the array when you are already in the middle). It is enough to compare each consecutive pair of elements, which is easily done:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5].each_cons(2).all? {|a, b| a < b }
```

If you *really absolutely MUST* compare triples, that is also easily done:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5].each_cons(3).all? {|a, b, c| a < b && b < c }
```

And if you want to make the size of the sliding window generic, then you can do something like this:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5].each_cons(n).all? {|window| 
  window.each_cons(2).map {|a, b| a < b }.inject(:&) 
}
```

Comment: `each_cons` is the way to go, but I think the OP wants `each_cons(3)`

Comment: `a < b < c` is the same as `a < b && b < c`, unless someone is able to change `b` while iterating, which, as I said, leads to much bigger problems.

Comment: Oh my, I need more coffee ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> I need to compare each value in ruby array with previous and next
>   value.

This method takes an array and a comparison method such as `:<`, `:>` or `:==` etc

```
def prev_next arr, com
  arr.map.with_index { |e,i|
    if i == 0
      [ e,
        e.send(com,arr[i.succ])
      ]
    elsif i == arr.length-1
      [ e.send(com,arr[i.pred]),
        e
      ]
    else
      [ e.send(com,arr[i.pred]),
        e, 
        e.send(com,arr[i.succ])
      ]
    end
  }
end

arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
p prev_next(arr,:<)
#=> [[1, true], [false, 2, true], [false, 3, true], [false, 4, true], [false, 5]]
```

Note the second parameter can be passed as a string or a symbol because `send` is clever enough to convert strings to symbols.

*Notable methods: [Object#send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Object.html#method-i-send), [Fixnum#succ](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Fixnum.html#method-i-succ) and [Integer#pred](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Integer.html#method-i-pred)*

Answer (score 1):

Now I totally agree with Jörg here that `each_cons` is the way to go and you should probably look for some other structure of the data if comparing the data is this complicated.

With that said. Nothing prevents normal index lookups in Ruby, and if nothing else works just implement your requirements in a simple case statement:

```
my_array = [1,2,4,5]

my_array.size.times do |ix|
    case ix
      when 0 then my_array[ix] == my_array[ix+1]
      when my_array.size-1 then my_array[ix] == my_array[ix-1]
      else my_array[ix-1] == my_array[ix] == my_array[ix+1]
    end
end
```